# Converting SUM IIF to regular IIF

Tags: ms-access

I have the following select code:

```
Sum(IIf(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_BTH_DT<=#12/31/1958# And     O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT<=#12/31/1988#,1,0)) AS RE2013, Sum(IIf    (O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_BTH_DT<=#12/31/1960# And O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT<=#12/31/1990#,1,0)) AS     RE2015, Sum(IIf(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_BTH_DT<=#12/31/1963# And     O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT<=#12/31/1993#,1,0)) AS RE2018
```

As it stands it tallies the total number of people that fall into each category, I am trying to change it to where instead of 3 columns with counts it is 1 column that has the specific year fitting the criteria. IE if someone falls under the RE2013 criteria it will have listed 2013 as the result. So instead of counts I need it to make a list. I rarely use Access so the coding is still very foreign to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
IIf(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_BTH_DT<=#12/31/1958# And O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT<=#12/31/1988#,"RE2013",IIf (O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_BTH_DT<=#12/31/1960# And O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT<=#12/31/1990#,"RE2015",IIf(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_BTH_DT<=#12/31/1963# And O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT<=#12/31/1993#,"RE2018",0)))
```

Might need to add a "(" somewhere, but that should be close to the answer.

Comment: That only returns "0" or blanks. It does not return the Years

Comment: Might need to put quotes around RE2013, et al. It probably thinks they're column names and they're actually text.  I updated the code to include them, let me know if that works.